# What's the difference between "along with" and "together with"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I keep hearing this phrase in the end of news release on the radio:

> Thanks for listening. I am Mike Widword along with Lizz Cai

meaning that two anchors were involved in casting this news.
I wonder why not say "together with Lizz Cai"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, I think it would be better just to say:

> Thanks for listening. I am Mike Widword with Lizz Cai

Which makes perfect sense.

*Along with* and *together with* don't have too much of a different meaning. Although *along with* sort of implies a dependence on the two subjects.

For example, you are at a private party and you were only able to get in because   Sally is a member and you were her guest. When someone asks you:

> How did you get into this party? I thought it was for members only.

You could respond:

> I came along with Sally.

Which sort of implies that Sally is the reason you were able to get in. This makes more sense than:

> I came together with Sally.

Which means the same thing, but sort of implies the fact that you came with her is not important to the answer. But if you want to use *together*, it would be better to say:

> Sally and I came together.

And, of course, there is nothing wrong with:

> I came with Sally

Answer (score 5):

Both seem perfectly fine to use interchangeably. It is the context in which you use them that matters, if at all.

Like, I'd say "along with" when I refer to a person(s) and 'together with' for things; for teams/groups i use both as it fits.

However, at times, 'together with' can be used while referring to people; for example - "I was able to crack the code *together with* my partner." Here, 'along with' doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Perhaps, because the two newscasters can participate in casting the same news release only in one-by-one format (if both of them start reporting at the same time they will simply create too much noise), while the act of cracking the code can really be performed simultaneously by two or more people thinking over the code, what do you think?